# Why SP browser displays different font size from PC emulators browser in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

My two pictures show a same web page. One is accessed from iOS simulator and another is  from PC simulator.
Their displayed size is same(e.g. iPhone X) but, their font size are slightly different nevertheless same webpage.

[image]

Why do they do so? It may be clew that the page have iframe and the main head has

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

and iframe have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=275, height=742, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

the width and height calculated extracts omitting gaps.
We want to know any possibilities that caused and welcome to any helps.
Our goals is PC browser design and how do we make it same about sp browser?

Comment: Maybe a font size in system settings or pixel density.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thank you for your advise. This is caused by `-webkit-text-size-adjust`. As first, I add these style to body  element of outer html not iframe. This feature affects in iframe, so we need to add the styles to iframe body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some smartphone browser, text-size-adjust property auto as default.
It sometimes affects font-size unexpectedly.In our case,

```
 body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    text-size-adjust: none;
  }
```

the styles can make it disable. They needs to be in iframe if it affects iframe element styles.